# The conditional statement is in R

Tags: r

I am new to The R program, Now I want to compare the values in “L” one by one with those in “Lmin” and “Lmax”, and assign it to “result” if the conditions are satisfied. Finally, I get the vector “result”, which is the value that can have multiple conditions satisfied.My program is below, but it can't realize the function I just said. How do I need to modify it?

```
DN<-1.1
Lmin<-DN/5
Lmax<-DN
L<-c(0.15,0.2,0.3,0.45,0.6)
n<-length(L)
result_baffle<-0
for(j in 1:n){
if(Lmin<=L[j]&&L[j]<=Lmax)
{
  result[i]<-L[j]  
}
else{
  break("There is no proper value")
  }
}
 result
```

Comment: Do you just want all the `L`'s that are `>=` to the min and `<=` to the max? If so, you don't need loops: `L[L >= Lmin & L <= Lmax]`

Comment: Yes, All values in "L" are compared with "Lmin" and "Lmax", and those satisfying the conditions are put into "result". Can you give you the code, I still haven't achieved what I wanted.

Comment: `result <- L[L >= Lmin & L <= Lmax]` does it I believe.